# Always indent in vim

Tags: vim, indentation

So far I've always used xemacs for source code editing (C++), but for several reasons i'd like to switch to or at least try out **vim**. One of the very basic things is indentation, where I'm super happy with xemacs behaviour. However I have yet to find a solution for having this behaviour in vim.

What I'm talking about is basically the ability to press `Tab` in any position of a line, and the line will always be indented to the correct level. This means:

1) pressing `Tab` multiple times will *not* indent multiple times, instead the text will be (re-)aligned to the indentation level suitable for the current code

2) pressing `Tab` e.g. in the middle of a word will *not* insert spaces or a tab in between this word, but rather indent the whole line

Is it possible to achieve this with vim?

Currently I have:

```
filetype indent plugin on
set cident
set autoindent
set shiftwidth=3
set softtabstop=3
set expandtab
```

Comment: I don't know whether it is possible to achieve what you want, but you can use `<cntl>-t` and `<cntl>-d` anywhere in insert mode to change the indentation level of the current line.

Comment: Trying to turn vi into Emacs will make you miserable. They each have different paradigms and strengths. The question reminds me of a programmer I once knew who wrote a set of macros to make a C compiler parse BASIC syntax. Square peg, round hole.

Comment: I think my question is not exactly tied to emacs, but instead of the indenting behaviour, which I found to be superior to any other style. E.g. in XCode you can have the very same behaviour, so this not only works for emacs/xemacs.
@cmaster: Unfortunately `C-t / C-d` is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In normal mode, pressing `==` should fix the indentation of the current line.

You can fix the indentation of several lines by:

- selecting them and pressing `=`,
- using a motion, `=}`,
- using a text-object, `=ip`.

In insert mode, you can fix the indentation of the current line with `<C-o>==` but the insertion point moves as well. You are not supposed to do that kind of thing in insert mode anyway.

Comment: `==` essentially does what I what. I'd like to have it some other key, but basically thats it.
Its okay that it "only" works in normal mode, after all I have to get around the different modes in vim anyway and get used to it.